# How to perform specific task in IIS

Tags: iis, webserver

I got kind of a weird question...

I want my IIS server to automatically show a specific page if there's a specific file present on the server... Basically, if there is something wrong or whatever, the file will exist and a safe page will be displayed. I know that this exists by I don't remember how it's called and can't find any info.

I don't know if I'm explaining my self right, but can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

[You are looking for custom 404 error page](http://ask.enquiro.com/2008/how-to-create-a-custom-404-error-page-in-microsoft-iis/).

Comment: Right.... So what if I making changes or whatever..?!? I want something that does all! 
Something that forces de server to redirect every single requests to that page!

Comment: In that case (you are down for maintenance that is) you just redirect to the same custom page as the 404.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is using ASP.NET, use the [app_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx) file to force an application to completely shut down and display the contents of that file on every request.